# Microsoft Teams in PODMAN

Tags: linux, fedora, container, microsoft-teams

I want to run Microsoft Teams in a container.

My desktop and laptop environments are built from the Fedora 32 Cinnamon spin.

The reason I want to run teams in a container, is that I have to use it to work with a particular colleague. But every time I run teams, it reinserts itself into the autostart list and then pops up at my next login to insist that I also login to teams.  No amount of toggling options in teams or autostart, or explicit deletion from autostart, changes this behavior.

A set of step by step instructions for the simplest possible way to run teams in a container, would be very much appreciated.

Comment: You should be able to use standard Docker images with `podman`.  Have you checked out the official [Microsoft Teams Docker image](https://hub.docker.com/r/microsoft/teams-docker)?  `podman pull docker.io/microsoft/teams-docker:latest` should get you going.

Comment: There is an option in `teams` to **really** shutdown when you quit and to also not autostart.

Comment: @GracefulRestart  I tried that one, it does not run

Comment: @rickhg12hs  I tried that, it re-installs and reverts the next time I run it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It’s not quite a container in the Podman sense, but I run [Teams in Flatpak](https://flathub.org/apps/details/com.microsoft.Teams) when I have to:

```
flatpak install flathub com.microsoft.Teams
flatpak run com.microsoft.Teams
```

Flatpak itself is packaged in Fedora:

```
sudo dnf install flatpak
```

And, it may be necessary to add the flathub repository for the above install command:

```
flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo
```

Comment: Thank you, that seems promising.  But,  the first command, flatpak install...  returns an error,   "No remote refs found similar to flathub"

Comment: After a quick search, I found flatpak remote-add --if-not-exists flathub https://dl.flathub.org/repo/flathub.flatpakrepo     I have no idea what the consequences are, it asks for several permissions.   Anyway, if you fixup the answer I will try to remember to come back and mark it correct.

Comment: Oops. still not quite there.  It runs but it is not letting me login.   I am not quite sure how this will work with the meetings link to a meeting that i usually receive by email.

Comment: Now it works.    I  received a link for a meeting, clicked on it, and it opened the flatpak!  Amazing.